# WP Super Cache - prevent caching for php in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, super

I have a Wordpress site with my own custom php code in header.php for a browser checker with ifs.

When I use WP Super Cache every time my php code doesn't work, I think its because the result from my browser checker is cached. I have tried many different options in WP Super Cache.
How can I prevent WP Super Cache from caching just the header.php file.

Comment: The answer in this link might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70813/wp-super-cache-exclude-file-from-caching